# indexPathForSelectedRow returning nil but not deselected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

In my prepareForSegue method, I am trying to use the table view cell tapped to set the data for my destination view controller, but the app crashes stating

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I can't understand why the indexPathForSelectedRow would be returning nil. I looked around at responses similar to my question and they suggested the problem might have been deselecting the selected row, but I don't think that is my problem. Does anyone know what it might be?

```
class ActivityTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var activities: [Activity] = []

    func generateActivities() {
        let sidecar = Activity(name: "Sidecar Doughnuts", type: "Food", area: "Santa Monica", address: "631 Wilshire Blvd. Santa Monica, California 90401")
        activities.append(sidecar)

        let roseCafe = Activity(name: "Rose Cafe", type: "Food", area: "Venice", address: "220 Rose Ave, Venice, CA 90291")
        activities.append(roseCafe)

        let milkShop = Activity(name: "The Milk Shop", type: "Food", area: "Beverly Hills", address: "7290 BEVERLY BLVD. LOS ANGELES, CA 90036")
        activities.append(milkShop)

        let brentwoodMart = Activity(name: "Brentwood Mart", type: "Food", area: "Brentwood", address: "225 26th St, Santa Monica, CA 90402")
        activities.append(brentwoodMart)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        generateActivities()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activities.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "ActivityCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! ActivityCellTableViewCell

        let individualActivity = activities[indexPath.row]

        cell.activityCellTitle.text = individualActivity.name

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier != "showActivityDetails" { return }

        if let dest = segue.destination as? ViewController, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            dest.activityTypeLabel.text = activities[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].type
            dest.areaLabel.text = activities[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].area
            dest.addressLabel.text = activities[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].address
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are safely unwrapping the indexPath for the selected row, so I do not think that is why you're getting the crash.  I would guess that you forgot to hook up an `@IBOutlet` for one of those 3 labels you're trying to set on the `ViewController`, or if you aren't creating them with a Storyboard then maybe they're not initialized until `viewDidLoad` or one of the other lifecycle methods.

Comment: OP is trying to directly set the label instead of passing the value as a string and setting it in the `viewDidLoad` of the next `UIViewController`

Comment: Yes the problem was directly setting the label instead of passing the value and setting it in the viewDidLoad. Thank you.